# Programmatically go back

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my application, the user goes from Page A to Page B.

Is there any way to programmatically simulate the back button press? I have a button on Page B and when the user clicks it, I want to go BACK to page A. I don't want to use the `NavigationService` and navigate to page A, I want to go back to Page A as if the user clicked on the hardware back button. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Although you say you don't want to use it, the [NavigationService.GoBack method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.goback%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is the way to go:

```
if (this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    this.NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Comment: Oh yea, i didnt know this existed. What I said, was that I didnt want to use NavigationService.Navigate. The GoBack is the way to go! Thanks!

Comment: I updated the link in the answer as the existing one pointed to the WPF method not the Windows Phone one.

Comment: This code can take you back to the previous page but it doesn't actually clicks the back button. That is if you have event on BackKeyPress, it wont execute.

Answer (score 0):

A little addition to Michaël Hompus's answer -- on UWP both `CanGoBack` property and `GoBack` method are located in Page.Frame.